# After installing 16.04.1, while keeping an old home directory, I cannot read/write into it

Tags: 16.04

I was using 14.04 LTS on my machine. When I got the notification that I can upgrade to 16.04.1 LTS, I downloaded the iso in order to get a clean reinstall. I have `/` on sda1 and `/home` on sda2 (seperate partitions). While installing 16.04.1, I chose to format sda1 and use it as `/` and I chose to use sda2 as `/home`. I chose the same username and the same password as before. The install went fine.
After the first boot, I tried to log in, but it failed. I can go to a virtual terminal and log in using my usual credentials. I can cd to `/home/user/Downloads` for example and all my files in the subfolders of the home directory seem to be there. Yet, when I do `ls` while in `~` I get the following error:

```
ls: relocation error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: symbol __libc_vfork, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

When I try to do `nano ~/.bashrc` I simply get a segmentation error. But the bash seems to have loaded my bashrc, since it looks like my usual bash. `touch test` gives me the same, while doing `touch test` in `~/Downloads` works fine.

When I boot from my installation device, I can mount the partition sda2 and read fine from it. Writing is only possible by using `sudo`.

Any ideas what this is all about? Also: I have never used encryption of my home directory.

[EDIT]: The `dmesg` tells me (after trying to log in into the graphic interface)

```
traps: gnome-session[3282] general protection ip:[hex numbers] sp:[more hex] error:0 in libc.so.6[even more hex]
```

[EDIT]: I cannot do `ls` while in `~`, but I can do `ls ~` while in `/` and even in `/home`. I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 2):

Probably something went wrong with files ownership settings (can be checked `ls -al /home/USER`). You can repair it by:

```
sudo chown USER /home/USER/ -Rv
```

Comment: I just did this (removing the `v` option speeds this process up a lot), but I didn't fix anything. My user had the same UID (1000) in the old and in the new installation.

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb right now. This answer is likely to be unhelpful to anyone, but it solved my problem. I had (I don't really know why) a file called `libc.so.6` lying around in my home directory. I removed it via `rm ~/libc.so.6` while not being in `~` and it fixed everything.